# How do i prevent my child node to rotate with its parent?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Since Cocos2d v2.0 no longer has honorParentTransform, what should we use?

Inverted rotations do not work for particles.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add it as child but to the same parent. Then synchronize position every update.

PS: honorParentTransform may still exist under a different name, check the API reference for CCNode properties.

Comment: ok,but then i should add a node to the parent (for example 10 points to the left)and use that as a reference, get that nodes world position, and set the child position to that world position?

Also, is not that too explensive for the cpu?

Comment: (laughs) if setting a position would be expensive for the CPU we wouldn't have games on iPhones ;) Anyhow, that is the principle. You can also add a CCNode, add your sprite (or whatever) to the node and also the particle (at an offset perhaps). If you want the sprite to rotate, rotate the sprite. If you want both sprite & particle to move, move the node.